# How can I generate a three column list of unique "combos"?

Tags: google-sheets, unique

I have three columns of information. For example: color, model, year.

Can I use the "unique" instruction to generate in three new columns each unique combination for color, model, year, each in one column?

ex.

```
color   model    year
red     sedan    2016
red     sedan    2020
black   truck    2018
```

Thanks!

Comment: Google-sheet or excel? What result do you expect from given sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your three headers are in A1, B1 and C1 with your data running A2:C. And suppose you want the unique combinations in E:G. First, be sure that the entire range E:G is empty. Then place the following formula in E1:

`=ArrayFormula({A1:C1;SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C,C2:C<>"")))))),"|")})`

The formula first reproduces the headers from A1:C1.

The combinations are formed by first concatenating each `UNIQUE` model (from a list that is `FILTER`ed to remove blanks) with each `UNIQUE` year (from a list that is also `FILTER`ed to remove blanks), with a pipe symbol between each as a separator that `SPLIT` will later use.

That grid of combinations is `FLATTEN`ed into a single column and then concatenated once more with a `UNIQUE` and `FILTER`ed list of the colors leading off, and again with a pipe symbol as a separator. Once more, the entire grid of results is `FLATTEN`ed into a single column.

Finally, `SPLIT` acts on the pipe symbols to separate the three pieces into their own columns under the headers.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX({A1:C1; UNIQUE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&
 TRANSPOSE(B2:B))&"×"&TRANSPOSE(C2:C)), "×"),
 "where Col3 is not null"))})
```

[image]

the task is simple: take column A and combine it with transposed column B. flatten the output in one single column and combine it with transposed column C and again flatten it into one single column. then split it and query out all combinations that have less than 3 columns. next, run it through unique to remove duplicates.